# using multiple php pages in html form validation

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am brand new to PHP and I am attempting to recreate a PDF in the shape of a PHP page.

Essentially, the user has to provide input in a number of fields, and then upon submitting, if the form validates successfully, it passes the html form to a new php page in a new window.

If it does not validate then the page reloads and indicates which fields need to be adjusted.
This is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" name="form">
```

What I have right now, is that when the form is submitted, it passes the form to itself:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 if (empty($_POST["schoolIn"])) {
    $schoolErr = "School Name is required";
 } else {
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$_POST["schoolIn"])) {
        $schoolErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 

     }
     else{
             $school = $_POST["schoolIn"];
     }
}

/*the rest of the validation goes here */
```

This seems to work great, however I am unsure how to submit the form to a new PHP document if all of these checks validate successfully.

On the form submission button, is there any way I can have some sort of conditional that checks if the form validates, and if so, submits it again to a new PHP file (say "submitted.php)? or am I thinking about this all wrong.

Comment: if form has submitted and there is no error then you can use header('location:yourgape.php');

Comment: what is the need of pass the values to new page ?

Comment: okay, using     header('location:submitted.php') seemed to work, but does that php page know all of the values contained in the first php?

Comment: then you can use session to store and send the value to other page

Comment: . just pass as a query parameter like this header('location:submitted.php?schoolIn='.$_POST['schoolIn']);  and access the value using $_GET['schoolIn'];

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

just pass value  as a query parameter like this

`header('Location:submitted.php?schoolIn='.$_POST['schoolIn']‌​);`

Access the value on destination page  using `$_GET['schoolIn'];`

**Method 2:**

you can store the post values into session and access it in anywhere .

```
   $_SESSION['form_values']=$_POST;
```

Access the value on destination page like this

```
   $_SESSION['form_values']['schoolIn'];
```

Note: Don't forgot to start the session start on wherever your using session .